# Is it possible to define a column as a variable in an insert query for php pgsql?

Tags: php, postgresql

```
$hr = '12';

$q = 'INSERT INTO table_value (date_recorded, day, $hr) VALUES(:a, :b, :c)';
```

Is it possible to define a column as a variable in an insert query for php pgsql?

Comment: Well, yes - the SQL is just a string from PHP - but it can be opening a can of worms, that variable should never under any circumstance be user input. Usually column-names can't be purely numeric though.

Comment: Column name `12`?

Comment: Also relevant here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: @u_mulder [why not ?](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ksj3uyxz5ogheQNnCUXr2e/0) :p

Comment: yes the column is 12 but can change it to something like _12

Comment: Nothing stops you from creating the string containing the query with anything from variable. However, you can't use prepared statements to define table or column names. `INSERT INTO :tablename (:colname) VALUES (...)` won't work

Comment: As @Qirel has pointed out, it will work, although you won't get any variable substitution if you use single quotes around the string, and you will need to enclose the value in double quotes if it's a number like `12`. e.g. `$q = "INSERT INTO table_value (date_recorded, day, \"$hr\") VALUES(:a, :b, :c)";`

Comment: Thanks guys , this for @Nick worked like charm!

Comment: @PaulKiarie good to hear you got it working.